# Impossible to install spookyjs

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, casperjs, node-modules, spookyjs

I want to install spookyjs and find it impossible to do so. I've tried three different ways:

1. Run the standard spookyjs package.json provided in [spookyjs github](https://github.com/SpookyJS/SpookyJS/blob/master/package.json).
   Then I try to run [hello.js](https://github.com/SpookyJS/SpookyJS/blob/master/examples/hello.js) and I am greeted with this error.

   ```
      C:\Users\User1\Desktop\test2>node hello.js
   events.js:183
         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
         ^

   Error: spawn casperjs ENOENT
       at _errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:190:19)
       at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:372:16)
       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
       at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:695:11)
       at startup (bootstrap_node.js:188:16)
       at bootstrap_node.js:609:3
   ```
2. Installed phantomjs and casperjs globally and `package.json` installed spooky and tiny-jsonrpc. I get the same error message.
3. Installed these dependencies from `package.json`

   ```
   "dependencies": {
       "spooky": "^0.2.5",
       "tiny-jsonrpc": "^2.0.1",
       "phantom": "^4.0.12",
       "casperjs": "^1.1.4"
   ```

I get the same error.

Comment: It's possible the package is dead because the last commit was in May 2016. You might have better luck checking out [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer)

Comment: I found out this: "https://cnpmjs.org/package/phantomjs". I will do further testing.

Comment: I used to use Phantomjs and unfortunately it is also being [deprecated](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=16511860) because the top developer is leaving due to chrome's headless browser and `puppeteer`.

Comment: Therefore i cannot use it? Can puppeteer do what spooky/casper/phantom toolchain offers?

Comment: You can use it but it will eventually be deprecated so it might be better to pivot to a toolchain that will survive. Google's headless api that I mentioned will most likely survive as it has a large company backing.

Comment: Well, after finding this link https://github.com/SpookyJS/SpookyJS/issues/71. The error stops.But unfortuantely when i run the example, nothing is logged on the screen.

Comment: Can puppeteer simulate a click on a specific div by its classname?

Comment: Yes, it can simulate a click... See [page.click on the api documentation](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageclickselector-options)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across this link:
[Issue](https://github.com/SpookyJS/SpookyJS/issues/71)

and it detailed the solution. That is this chunk of code:

```
const
  path = require('path'),
  _ = require('underscore')
;
var
  // close env to pass to spawn
  env = _.clone(process.env),
  // get the PATH - in my local Windows, it was Path
  envPath = env.PATH || env.Path,
  // get path to node_modules folder where casperjs and
  // phantomjs-prebuilt are installed
  // this will be different for you
  binDir = path.join(__dirname, './../../node_modules/.bin'),
  Spooky = require('spooky')
;
// update the path in the cloned env
env.PATH = env.Path = `${envPath};${binDir}`;


var spooky = new Spooky({
  child: {
    // spooky is trying to call casperjs.bat for windows
    // .bat doesn't work, so call the update .cmd file
    // this fixes issue 2 with the file
    command: /^win/.test(process.platform) ? 'casperjs.cmd' : 'casperjs',
    transport: 'http' ,
    spawnOptions: {
      // set the env using cloned version
      // this fixes issue 1 with the path
      env: env
    }
  },
  ...
```

So now the program runs without an error. Actually though it runs without anything, because while on the one hand no error pops up, on the other nothing pops up. I debbuged by putting console.log() inside spooky's callback function but nothing is displayed. That is for another question though...

But the error i was receiving has vanished and the interpreter runs the code.